# c# move item in listbox up and down

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I got a windows form application with a listbox that display content, I wanna be able to move the items from the listbox up and down, when a button is clicked. at the moment the items in the list box stored are in text file, which is loaded into configuration class when the application start. How would I move the items up/down and change the order in the text file?

my main application form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace company1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Configuration> lines = new List<Configuration>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
            //Read in every line in the file
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    string[] array = new string[] { "\\n" };
                    string[] parts = new string[3];
                    parts = line.Split(array, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    lines.Add(new Configuration(parts[0], int.Parse(parts[1]), int.Parse(parts[2])));
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }

            }
            listBox1.DataSource = lines;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
        }
    }
}
```

the configuration class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace company1
{
    class Configuration
    {
        string _CompanyName;
        int _Employees;
        int _Half;

        public Configuration(string companyname, int number_of_Employees, int half)
        {
            _CompanyName = companyname;
            _Employees = number_of_Employees;
            _Half = half;
        }

        //program properties and validation
        public string CompanyName
        {
            set
            {
                _CompanyName = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _CompanyName;
            }
        }// End of levelname validation

        //program properties and validation
        public int EmployeesNumber
        {
            set
            {
                _Employees = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _Employees;
            }
        }// End of levelname validation

        //program properties and validation
        public int Half
        {
            set
            {
                _Half = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _Half;
            }
        }// End of levelname validation
    }


}
```

any help appreciated, been trying for days to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// change the items in source list
var tmpLine = lines[10];
lines[10] = lines[9];
lines[9] = tmpLine;

// refresh datasource of listbox
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an extension method for list to move items based on index:

```
public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static void Move<T>(this List<T> list, int index1, bool moveDown = true)
    {
        if (moveDown)
        {
            T temp = list[index1];
            list[index1] = list[index1 + 1];
            list[index1 + 1] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            T temp = list[index1];
            list[index1] = list[index1 - 1];
            list[index1 - 1] = temp;

        }
    }
}
```

Then in Code you can:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
            Console.WriteLine("Original List");
            foreach (int i in list)
            {
                Console.Write(i + ",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Move Index 2 Down");
            list.Move(2);
            foreach (int i in list)
            {
                Console.Write(i + ",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Move Index 3 Up");
            list.Move(3, false);
            foreach (int i in list)
            {
                Console.Write(i + ",");
            }
```

Output will be:

```
Original List
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
Move Index 2 Down
1,2,4,3,5,6,7,
Move Index 3 Up
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
```

Comment: Do I put the extension method inside the configuration class, or main program?

Comment: you can put the extension method in any class where it is available to all the code, Its a generic method and will work on list of all types. I am not sure about your configuration class, but if it is available through out the code, you can put it there. If you put it inside the main program then it may only be available to that particular namespace

Comment: nope i keep getting an error: (Error 1 Extension method must be defined in a top level static class; ExtensionClass is a nested class) looking online trying to find solution of it

Comment: @Raphael1, don't put this class inside a class, Just create a separate class file for it and put it in there.